# Reading data from X24C44 NOVRAM

Tags: spi, ram

I have some X24C44 NOVRAM ICs on circuit boards which I wish to read data from. These devices were used as an identification for each board, for example board 1 contains ID "BOARD1ID001". Is it possible to obtain the identification stored in each RAM if I don't know what pattern was used to store the data? How can I interpret the binary data?

Comment: Can you get the data dumped out of them, or do you need help with that?

Comment: I never used RAM so it is my first time trying to read data from such device. Some help would be usedful.

Comment: It's a SPI device -- so something like a Bus Pirate in SPI mode, along with reading the friendly datasheet, should be a good start.

Answer (score 1):

The Xicor X24C44 is a proprietary combination of RAM and serial EEPROM with SPI-look serial interface, with 32 bytes capacity. To read the internal data, you need a special or universal programmer. For a list of supporting programmers, Google for "programmer for X24C44", there are plenty.

After you get the binary data from EEPROM, interpretation of binary bytes into ASCII using any decent text editor will likely help, unless the original manufacturer resorted to some encryption for some silly reason.

To read the data from X24C44, you might need to de-solder (or pull it out if socketed), although you might be lucky, and be able to read it on UNPOWERED board if the board wiring does not interfere with programmer.

Comment: You should be able to do it with anything that can talk SPI -- it's more like a serial EEPROM in that regard than it is something that *requires* an EPROM burner...